# How can I evaluate if empty using razor

Tags: c#, if-statement, razor, sitefinity

I would like to wrap this code into a condition that only shows if eventtypes is not empty. I´m getting some empty values and I would like to hide the span element.

```
<span class="event-type">
    @string.Join(",", item.GetFlatTaxons("eventtypes").Select(t => t.Title))
</span>
```

Comment: It worked @CodeCaster can you please post as answer. Apologies for the unclear question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply store the list in a variable and check if it contains any elements using Linq:

```
@{
    var eventTypes = item.GetFlatTaxons("eventtypes");
}

@if (eventTypes.Any())
{
    <span class="event-type">
        @string.Join(",", eventTypes.Select(t => t.Title))
    </span>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `Title` is a string:

```
<span class="event-type">
    @string.Join(",", item.GetFlatTaxons("eventtypes").Where(i => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(i.Title)).Select(t => t.Title))
</span>
```